# Remove content from a child in Paned

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

At `PyGObject` API Reference there is methods to add and pack childs in a `Gtk.Paned`.

```
add1(child)
add2(child)
```

But I caannot find any way to remove existent content from `child2` before adding a new content on it

How can I change `child2` content at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I can finally empty child2 with:

```
builder.get_object("splitpanel").get_child2().destroy()
```